# Understanding readMaybe (Text.Read)

Tags: haskell

I'm currenlty learning Haskell and have questions regarding this example found in [Joachim Breitner's online course CIS194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall16/lectures/06-io-and-monads.html):

```
import Text.Read
main = putStrLn "Hello World. Please enter a number:" >>
       getLine >>= \s ->
       case readMaybe s of   -- why not `readMaybe s :: Maybe Int` ?!
           Just n ->  let m = n + 1 in
                      putStrLn (show m)
           Nothing -> putStrLn "That’s not a number! Try again"
```

The code does exactly what expected, that is it returns an integer +1 if the input is an integer and it returns "That’s not a number! Try again" otherwise (*e.g.* if the input is a `Double`).
I don't understand why `readMaybe s` only returns `Just n` if `n` is of type `Int`. The type of `readMaybe` is `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a` and therefore I thought it would only work if the line read instead:

```
case readMaybe s :: Maybe Int of
```

In fact if I just prompt `> readMaybe "3"` in ghci, it returns `Nothing`, whereas `> readMaybe "3" :: Maybe Int` returns `Just 3`.

To sum up, my question is the following: how does the compiler now that `s` is parsed to an `Int` and not something else (*e.g.* `Double`) without the use of `:: Maybe Int`? Why does it not return `Nothing` everytime ?

I hope my question was clear enough, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The context of `readMaybe s` tells us that it's a `Num a => Maybe a`, defaulting makes it a `Maybe Integer`.

---

We have to look at all places where the result of `readMaybe` is used to determine its type.

We have

- `Nothing`, which doesn't tell us *aynthing* about `a`
- `Just n`, and `n` is used in the context `m = n + 1`.

Since `m = n + 1`, we now know that `n`'s type must be an instance of `Num`, since `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and `1 :: Num a => a`. At this point the type isn't clear, therefore it [gets `default`ed](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html):

> #### 4.3.4  Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations
>
> ```
> topdecl   ->  default (type1 , ... , typen)   (n>=0)
> ```
>
> A problem inherent with Haskell -style overloading is the possibility of an ambiguous type. For example, using the read and show functions defined in Chapter 10, and supposing that just Int and Bool are members of Read and Show, then the expression
>
> ```
> let x = read "..." in show x -- invalid
> ```
>
> is ambiguous, because the types for show and read,
>
> ```
> show  :: forall a. Show a =>a ->String
> read  :: forall a. Read a =>String ->a
> ```
>
> could be satisfied by instantiating a as either Int in both cases, or Bool. Such expressions are considered ill-typed, a static error.
>
> We say that an expression e has an ambiguous type if, in its type forall u. cx =>t, there is a type variable u in u that occurs in cx but not in t. Such types are invalid.

The `default`s defined in the Haskell report are `default (Integer, Double)`, e.g. GHC tries `Integer` first, and if that doesn't work it tries to use `Double`.

Since `Integer` is a valid type in the context `m = n + 1`, we have `m :: Integer`, therefore `n :: Integer`, and at last `readMaybe s :: Maybe Integer`.

If you want to disable `default`s, use `default ()` and you'll be greeted by ambiguous types errors, just as you expected.

Comment: Good answer!  If I want `Int`, I usually write a type signature for some helper function or variable, but another good place to put the type coercion here would be the constant. In GHCI, I would often write `(1::Int)`. rather than `1`.

Comment: @Davislor you can also use `asTypeOf` if you already have variables with a certain type, e.g. ```bijection x = read x (show x) `asTypeOf` x```.

Comment: I don’t think that snippet is quite right, but good suggestion.

Comment: @Davislor yeah, it should have been ```bijection x = read (show x) `asTypeOf` x```.

Answer (score 1):

There indeed some underlying magic, due to how type inference works.

Here's a simpler example, run inside GHCi:

```
> print (1 :: Integer)
1
> print (1 :: Float)
1.0
Prelude> print 1
1
```

In the last line, `1` is a polymorphic value of type `Num a => a`, i.e. a value inside any numeric type like `Integer` and `Float`. If we consider that value inside type `Integer`, we print it as "1". If we consider it as a `Float`, we print it as "1.0". Other numeric types may even have different print formats.

Still, GHCi in the last line decides that `1` is an `Integer`. Why?

Well, it turns out that the code is ambiguous: after all `1` could be printed in different ways! Haskell in such cases raises an error, due to the ambiguity. However, it makes an exception for numeric types (those inc lass `Num`), to be more convenient to program. Concretely, when a numeric type is not precisely determined by the code, Haskell uses its *defaulting rules*, which specify which numeric types should be used.

[GHC can warn](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html?highlight=default#ghc-flag--Wtype-defaults) when defaulting happens, if wanted.

Further, the types are propagated. If we evaluate

```
case readMaybe s of
  Just x -> let z = x + length ['a','z']
            in ...
```

GHC knows that `length` returns an `Int`. Also, `(+)` operates only on arguments of the same type, hence `x` has to be an `Int` as well. This in turns implies that the call `readMaybe s` has to return `Maybe Int`. Hence, the right `Read` instance for `Int`s is chosen.

Note how this information is propagated backwards by the type inference engine, so that the programmer does not have to add type annotations which can be deduced from the rest of the code. It happens very frequently in Haskell.

One can always be explicit, as in

```
readMaybe s :: Maybe Int
-- or, with extensions on, one can mention the variable part of the type, only
readMaybe s @ Int
```

If you prefer, feel free to add such annotations. Sometimes, they make the code more readable since they document your intent. Whoever reads the code, can immediately spot which `Read` instance is being used here without looking at the context.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I added `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` so that I get a handful of helping warnings. I did not know about type propagation (let alone backward propagation !), it seems to be very powerful indeed.